# The soul and Sleep

Tags: sleep, soul

I’ve heard from a Rabbi that the falling feeling you get while your sleeping that wakes you up (known as the hipnic jerk) is your soul falling back into your body. Are there any other sources that speak about common things that happen during your sleep that are actually actions of your soul? This interests me greatly. Thanks!